# why the function is not being called?

Tags: javascript, html

I am testing a thing based upon the URL . If the URL ends with *logout.jsp* then the logout message should get displayed 
and if URL ends with *index.jsp* the message should not get displayed . For doing this I used 
`document.getElementById("id").hidden = value`. But this doesn't work.Infact the function is not being called. 
I don't know what the problem is.

**HTML snippet**

```
<table id="LogoutMessage" onload="urlCheck()">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h2>You are successfully logged out !</h2>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

**javascript function**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function urlCheck() {
        alert("in the function urlCheck");
        if(document.URL.endsWith() = "logout.jsp")
            document.getElementById("LogoutMessage").hidden = false;
        else if(document.URL.endsWith() = "index.jsp")
            document.getElementById("LogoutMessage").hidden = true;                
    }
</script>
```

**Whole page**  *In JSP*

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>PhotoArtWork</title>
    <jsp:include page="reusable/stylesheets.html" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr-1.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <jsp:include page="reusable/header.html" />
    <!-- begin content --><div id="site_content">
        <table id="LogoutMessage" onload="urlCheck()">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h2>You are successfully logged out !</h2>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
  <ul class="slideshow">
    <li class="show"><img width="950" height="450" src="images/home_1.jpg" alt="&quot;You can put a caption for your image right here&quot;"></li>
    <li><img width="950" height="450" src="images/home_2.jpg" alt="&quot;You can put a description of the image here if you like, or anything else if you want.&quot;"></li>
    <li><img width="950" height="450" src="images/home_3.jpg" alt="&quot;You can put a description of the image here if you like, or anything else if you want.&quot;"></li>

  </ul>
  </div>
<!-- end content -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    function urlCheck() {
        alert("in the function urlCheck");
        if(document.URL.endsWith() = "logout.jsp")
            document.getElementById("LogoutMessage").hidden = false;
        else if(document.URL.endsWith() = "index.jsp")
            document.getElementById("LogoutMessage").hidden = true;                
    }
</script>
<jsp:include page="reusable/footer.html" />
</body>
</html>
```

What is the problem ?

Comment: Why would you do this with JavaScript and not on the server. Seems like a very bad idea.

Comment: What is the Javascript function `endsWith`?

Comment: Do you have a library that is adding the string method `.endsWith()` because that is not a standard method?

Comment: I recommend against `<... onload="urlCheck()">`, better fire this after the dom element is created (by moving the script at the bottom for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `.hidden` attribute. It is part of the element's style and you would use visibility.

```
document.getElementById("LogoutMessage").style.visibility = "hidden"; // or "visible"
```

And if I had to guess, you want to use `display` and not `hidden`.

```
document.getElementById("LogoutMessage").style.display = "none"; // or "block"
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be document.getElementById("LogoutMessage").style.visibility = 'hidden'

Comment: @anuragsn7 Caught me in my edit! Morning coffee has not kicked in. :)

Comment: why the function is not being called ?

Comment: I have implemented the same on server. Why do you call this a better idea as compared to JS ?

Answer (score 1):

To have your code called, either do:

`<body onload="urlCheck()">`

or put the script at the very end of the `body` tag, with just the inner code of your function.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't have a native `endsWith`. So you have to create one first

```
String.prototype.endsWith = function(suffix) {
    return this.indexOf(suffix, this.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
};
```

Also, there is no <strike>`style.hidden property`</strike>. Please use `style.display` instead

Thecorrect function `urlCheck` should be like this

```
function urlCheck() {
    alert("in the function urlCheck");
    if(document.URL.endsWith("logout.jsp"))
        document.getElementById("LogoutMessage").style.display= 'block';
    else if(document.URL.endsWith("index.jsp"))
        document.getElementById("LogoutMessage").style.display= 'none';
}
```

Oh and as Mic says please call the function onload like this.

```
window.onload = function() { urlCheck(); }
```

Comment: i think Suhail wants to show the message if 'logout.jsp' is there in the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery. Include

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and use

```
$('#LogoutMessage').hide();
```

for hiding the message and

```
$('#LogoutMessage').show();
```

for showing the message

To call your function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    urlCheck();
})
function urlCheck() {
    var url = document.URL;
    var urlArr = url.split('/')
    if($.inArray('logout.jsp', urlArr))
    {
        $('#LogoutMessage').show();
    }
    if($.inArray('index.jsp', urlArr))
    {
        $('#LogoutMessage').hide();
    }
}
```

Try the above .